How to calculate the difference between two dates in SQL?
I want to calculate the difference between two dates in SQL. For example, if I have the following dates:

start_date: '2024-11-01'
end_date: '2024-11-28'

How can I calculate the difference in:

Days
Months
Years

I know that some SQL dialects (e.g., MySQL, PostgreSQL) have specific functions, but I’m looking for a solution that works across SQL Server if possible.
What is the most efficient way to achieve this in SQL Server?
this is what i tried to do
for days
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF('2024-11-28', '2024-11-01') AS days_difference;

for months
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2024-11-01', '2024-11-28') AS months_difference;

for years
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2024-11-01', '2024-11-28') AS years_difference;

but it was showing me an error

I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

"but it was showing me an error" You forgot to include that error in your post.

Try DATEDIFF() e.g. DATEDIFF(DAY, '2024-11-28', '2024-11-01') although you'll probably want those dates swapped if you are expecting a positive value. See docs

If you use SQL Server, add the  tag. (MS SQL Server doesn't support the ANSI/ISO SQL date/time functionality.)

In sql server, you can use DATEDIFF function to calculate difference indays, months, and years between two dates.
For example Difference in Days:
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2024-11-01', '2024-11-28') AS DifferenceInDays;


To perform calculations via sql server
For days
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'2024-11-01','2024-11-28') AS days_difference;
For months
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,'2024-11-01','2024-11-28') AS months_difference;
For years
For days
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR,'2024-11-01','2024-11-28') AS years_difference;
